# Rendering a Semi-Transparent Sprite to a Texture

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a 1024x1024 background texture and am trying to render a 100x100 sprite (also stored in a texture) to the bottom left corner of the background texture.

I want to render the sprite at 50% opacity. This needs to be done in the CPU, not the GPU using a shader. Most examples I've found are using shaders to achieve this.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean from CPU-side opengl commands, therefore using the fixed function (or fixed pipeline). I deduce this from the "no shader" request.
Because "doing this on CPU" would actually really mean do a retrieval/mapping of the texture to access it on CPU, loop on pixels, and copy back result to graphic card using glTexImage or unmap the texture afterward. this last approach would be terribly inefficient.
So you just need to activate blending.

```
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

and render in order: background, then a little quad with your 100x100 image after. it will take the alpha channel from your 100x100 image to make the blend. You could set it to a constant 50% from an image editing tool.

Comment: Can you please also point me to how I can actually draw the sprite on the texture too?

Comment: well yes, with an old style opengl context, you can just do glTexImage2d to uplodad your image data, then glBindTexture, then glBegin with quads, call 4 times glVertex2f and glTexCoord to draw the quad, then glEnd. that should do it. I'm sure there are some tutorials on nehe.net for that